# Fully Object Oriented framework in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, oop

I want to create a 100% object oriented framework in PHP with no procedural programming at all, and where everything is an object. Much like Java except it will be done in PHP.

Any pointers at what features this thing should have, should it use any of the existing design patterns such as MVC? How creating objects for every table in the database would be possible, and how displaying of HTML templates etc would be done?

Please don't link to an existing framework because I want to do this on my own mainly as a learning excercise. You **will** be downvoted for linking to an existing framework as your answer and saying 'this does what you want'.

Some features I'd like to have are:

- Very easy CRUD page generation
- AJAX based pagination
- Ajax based form validation if possible, or very easy form validation
- Sortable tables
- Ability to edit HTML templates using PHP

Comment: Why the downvotes? For asking a genuine programming question?

Comment: How are you going to do fully OO programming with a script? One even that does not static type the variables. When you get this framework done, I think you will have recreated the Java. If you get this done, I would love to see a true OO script.

Comment: @Wolfman, PHP 5 supports static variables, I'm pretty sure

Comment: +1 for being crazy enough to try this.

Comment: Only worked with PhP 4, and under protest at that.

Comment: So your question is: what features should your web framework that you are inventing have? Isn't that kind of up to you? Do you mean rather: "what features do you guys like in a php framework"?

Comment: @WolfmanDragon, PHP5 does support static variables, I think the only major thing that makes less OO then other languages is that a class can only have on parent.

Comment: @teh_noob, actually java can also have only 1 parent

Comment: @Click Upvote, oh my bad I guess its C++ that is that way. Also I think PHP may be base off of Java so they should be similar, right?

Comment: I think what makes php less OO is that you can't have interfaces and packages. Or can you have interfaces?

Comment: @teh_noob, PhP is written in the C language, which is not OO. True OO means that EVERYTHING must be an object. Java itself defies this with its support of primitives. So if your language supports primitives, it is not TRUE OO. Splitting hairs, I know, but Java is just mostly OO. Smalltalk is more OO

Comment: @WolfmanDragon, When I said PHP is based of Java I meant, the was similar, not that it was written in Java. FYI, PHP is weakly typed but allows the use of primitives in its syntax and c++ too for that matter.

Comment: Don't do like rails and generate javascript code, please.

Comment: @wolf, i wouldn't want primitive types to be an Object anyways, that would just be frustrating and different from what you've been doing all along. But in Java you /can/ have primitives as objects if you wanted to

Comment: Good frameworks don't start as a product - they evolve as shared nbeeds & solutions are seen across multiple applications. Without knowing, from experience, what really needs a generic implementation and what should be application specific, how do you plan to identify what needs abstracting?

Comment: @YousufIqbal Heh, no. I thought about it but there's no good way of doing it. I'm trying to migrate to Java instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've gone through many of problems on your list, so let me spec out how I handle it. I am also OOP addict and find object techniques extremely flexible and powerful yet elegant (if done correctly).

**MVC** - yes, hands down, MVC is a standard for web applications. It is well documented and understandable model. Furthermore, it does on application level what OOP does on class level, that is, it keeps things separated. Nice addition to MVC is [Intercepting Filter](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/InterceptingFilter.html) pattern. It helps to attach filters for pre- and post-processing request and response. Common use is logging requests, benchmarking, access checking, caching, etc.

**OOP representation** of database tables/rows is also possible. I use [DAO](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) or [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) on daily basis. Another approach to ORM issues is [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) and [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html). Here's [example implementation](https://tigermouse.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tigermouse/lib/model/table-gateway/TableGateway.class.php) of TDG utilising `ArrayAccess` interface.

**HTML templates** also can be represented as objects. I use View objects in conjunction with Smarty template engine. I find this technique EXTREMELY flexible, quick, and easy to use. Object representing view should implement `__set` method so every property gets propagated into Smarty template. Additionally `__toString` method should be implemented to support views nesting. See example:

```
$s = new View();
$s->template = 'view/status-bar.tpl';
$s->username = "John Doe";
$page = new View();
$page->template = 'view/page.tpl';
$page->statusBar = $s;
echo $page;
```

Contents of `view/status-bar.tpl`:

```
<div id="status-bar"> Hello {$username} </div>
```

Contents of `view/page.tpl`:

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>
    <ul id="main-menu">.....</ul>
    {$statusBar}
    ... rest of the page ...
</body>
</html>
```

This way you only need to `echo $page` and inner view (status bar) will be automatically transformed into HTML. Look at [complete implementation here](https://tigermouse.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tigermouse/view/core-views/View.class.php). By the way, using one of Intercepting Filters you can wrap the returned view with HTML footer and header, so you don't have to worry about returning complete page from your controller.

The question of whether to use Ajax or not should not be important at time of design. The framework should be flexible enough to support Ajax natively.

**Form validation** is definitely the thing that could be done in OO manner. Build complex validator object using [Composite pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx). Composite validator should iterate through form fields and assigned simple validators and give you Yes/No answer. It also should return error messages so you can update the form (via Ajax or page reload).

Another handy element is automatic translation class for changing data in db to be suitable for user interface. For example, if you have INT(1) field in db representing boolean state and use checkbox in HTML that results in empty string or `"on"` in _POST or _GET array you cannot just assign one into another. Having translation service that alters the data to be suitable for View or for db is a clean way of sanitizing data. Also, complexity of translation class does not litter your controller code even during very complex transformations (like [the one converting Wiki syntax](https://tigermouse.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tigermouse/lib/translation/) into HTML).

Also **i18n** problems can be solved using object oriented techniques. I like using `__` function (double underscore) to get localised messages. The function instead of performing a lookup and returning message gives me a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object and pre-registers message for later lookup. Once Proxy object is pushed into View AND View is being converted into HTML, i18n backend does look up for all pre-registered messages. This way only one query is run that returns all requested messages.

**Access controll** issues can be addressed using Business Delegate pattern. I described it in my [other Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228672/php-access-control-system/325805#325805).

Finally, if you would like to play with existing code that is fully object oriented, take look at [Tigermouse framework](http://tigermouse.epsi.pl/). There are some UML diagrams on the page that may help you understand how things work. Please feel free to take over further development of this project, as I have no more time to work on it.

Have a nice hacking!

Comment: 1. Caching - in prefiltering if page is in cache then action is redirected to return cached page. 2. Benchmarking - postfiltering saves time of execution to file. 3. Formatting - postfilter wraps output with HTML <head>er. 4. Access checking - some actions may only be available to logged users.

Answer (score 17):

Now at the risk of being downvoted, whilst at the same time being someone who is developing their own framework, I feel compelled to tell you to at least get some experience using existing frameworks. It doesn't have to be a vast amount of experience maybe do some beginner tutorials for each of the popular ones.

Considering the amount of time it takes to build a good framework, taking the time to look into what you like and loathe about existing solutions will pale in comparison. You don't even need to just look at php frameworks. Rails, Django etc are all popular for a reason.

Building a framework is rewarding, but you need a clear plan and understanding of the task at hand, which is where research comes in.

Some answers to your questions:

- Yes, it should probably use MVC as the model view controller paradigm translates well into the world of web applications.
- For creating models from records in tables in your database, look into ORM's and the Active Record pattern. Existing implementations to research that I know of include Doctrine, more can be found by searching on here.
- For anything AJAX related I suggest using jQuery as a starting point as it makes AJAX very easy to get up and running.

Comment: +1 for good answer, looking at the competition will give you hints on how not to go wrong in your code and learn from their own mistake, even perhaps inspire you and making you view the task from another angle.

Answer (score 6):

Creating your own framework is a good way to gain an appreciation for some of the things that might be going on under the hood of other frameworks.  If you're a perfectionist like me, it gives you a good excuse to agonize over every little detail (e.g. is should that object be called X or Y, should I use a static method or an instance method for this).

I wrote my own (almost completely OO framework a while ago), so here's my advice:

- If you've worked with other frameworks before, consider what you liked/didn't like and make sure yours gives you exactly what you want.
- I personally love the MVC pattern, I wouldn't dream of doing a project without it.  If you like MVC, do it, if you don't don't bother.
- If you want to do JavaScript/AJAX stuff, do use a JavaScript library.  Coding all your own JavaScript from scratch teaches you a bit about the DOM and JavaScript in general, but ultimately its a waste of time, focus on making your app/framework better instead.
- If you don't want to adopt another framework wholesale, take a look at whether there are other open source components you like and might want to use, such as [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/), [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/), [ADOdb](http://phplens.com/adodb/), or [PEAR components](http://pear.php.net/).  Writing your own framework doesn't necessarily mean writing everything from scratch.
- Use design patterns where they make sense (e.g. singletons for database access perhaps), but don't obsess over them.  Ultimately do whatever you think produces the neatest code.
- Lastly, I learned a lot by delving into a bit of [Ruby on Rails philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails#Philosophy_and_design),  You may never use RoR (I didn't), but some of the concepts (especially Convention over Configuration) really resonated with me and really influenced my thinking.

Ultimately, unless your needs are special most people will be more productive if they adopt an existing framework.  But [reinventing the wheel does teach you more about wheels.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001145.html)

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of sounding glib, this seems to me like any other software project, in this sense:

You need to define your requirements clearly, including motivation and priorities:

- WHY do this? What are the key benefits you hope to realize? If the answer is "speed" you might do one thing, if it's "ease of coding" you might do another, if it's "learning experience" you might do a thid
- what are the main problems you're trying to solve? And which are most important? Security? Easy UI generation? Scalability?

The answer to "what features it should have" really depends on answers to questions like those above.

Comment: Good questions. They key benefits are ease/more enjoyable coding as well as speed, and the main problems are speed and UI generation/form validation.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Stop what you're doing.
2. It's already been done to death.
3. Click this [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) or that [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or maybe even this [Recess Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/).

Now, my reasons:

> ... if you've worked with developers at all, you've worked with developers that love reinventing the wheel for no good reason.  This is a very, very common failure pattern.
>
> ... they would go off and write hundreds and thousands of the crappiest languages you could possibly imagine ...
>
> ... "Oh, I'm gonna create my own framework, create my own everything," and it's all gonna be crappier than stuff you could just go out and get ...

from [StackOverflow Podcast # 3](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W56).

So, save yourself some time, and work on something that solves a problem for people like a web app that lets people automatically update Twitter when their cat's litter box needs cleaning. The problem of "Object Oriented PHP Framework" is done. Whatever framework you slap together will never be as reliable or useful or feature rich as any of the freely available, fully supported frameworks available **TODAY**.

This doesn't mean you can't have a learning experience, but why do it in the dark, creating a framework that will grow into a useless blob of code, leaving you without anything to show for your time? Develop a web app, something for people to use and enjoy, I think you'll find the experience incredibly rewarding and **EDUCATIONAL**.

Comment: Sorry, but the guy said he didn't want to hear this answer again, so I don't think it's right to shove it down his throat. If everyone stuck with the original frameworks, new frameworks would never get written. I, for one, believe in reinventing the wheel and encouraging others to do so. If they decide it wasn't the best choice, that's fine, but somewhere out there, some kid in his basement will create a framework/idea/innovation that works better than the ones out at the moment. Who cares if lots don't work? We need these 'pointless' experiments to help us grow! My two cents..

Answer (score 2):

I've got the perfect link for you my friend: http://nettuts.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1/. This is an awesome tutorial I have looked at, and its not too overwhelming. Plus look around the PHP section of that site I saw an article on CRUD. As for the AJAX look elsewhere, but you have to start somewhere, and this tutorial is awesome.

Note: this tutorial has 3 parts and I think it brings up MVC in the second instalment, but starts the first part using other methods.

Comment: Yah I was just kind of fooling around ;-), thanks for the up vote!

Answer (score 2):

Like Jim OHalloran said, writing your own framework gives you a very good insight into how other frameworks do things.

That said, I've written a data-access layer before that almost completely abstracted away any SQL. Application code could request the relevant object and the abstraction layer did lots of magic to fetch the data only when it was needed, didn't needlessly re-fetch, saved only when it was changed, and supported putting some objects on different databases. It also supported replicated databases, and respected replication lag, and had an intelligent collection object. It was also highly extensible: the core was parameter driven and I could add a whole new object with about 15 lines of code - and got all the magic for free.

I've also written a CRUD layout engine which was used for a considerable percentage of a site. The core was parameter driven so it could run list and edit pages for anything, once you wrote a parameter list. It automatically did pagination, save-new-delete support etc etc, leveraging the object layer above. It wasn't object-oriented in and of itself, but it could have been made so.

In other words, a object-oriented framework in PHP is not only possible, it can be very efficient. This was all in PHP 4, BTW, and I bumped up against what was possible with PHP 4 objects a couple of times. :-)

I never got as far as a central dispatch that called objects, but I wasn't far away. I've worked with several frameworks that do that, though, and the file layout can get hairy quickly. For that reason, I would go for a dispatch system that is only as complex as it needs to be and no more. A simple action/view (which is almost MVC anyway) should get you more than far enough.

Comment: Your framework sounds very interesting, care to share how your CRUD layout would be called for a given object, how the attributes, labels etc would be defined? I'd love to see

Comment: I'm not sure who owns the code, actually, me or a previuos employer. The layout was done with large array constants. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I initially started creating my own framework with similar ideals to your own. However, after a couple of months I realised I was re-creating work that had been done many times over. In the end I found an open source framework which was easily extendable and used it as a basis for my own development.

The features I implemented myself:

- MVC Architecture
- Authentication object
- Database access class
- URL rewriting config
- Pagination class
- Email class
- Encryption

The features I looked at and thought, forget it! I'll build on top of someone elses:

- Caching class
- Form validation class
- FTP class
- Plugin-ability classes

Of course, writing a framework that outperforms the open source options is possible, but why would you bother?

Answer (score 2):

It's true that some developers reinvent the wheel for no good reason. But because there are already good frameworks around doesn't mean that it's a waste of time doing one yourself. I started on one a while ago with no intention of using it for anything more than an exercise. I highly recommend doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The one, huge selling point I would look for in a new framework is that it would make writing *testable* code easy.

We typically work with Zend Framework, and it's mostly awesome, but trying to unit test/test drive ZF-based code is not far short of masochism.

If you could provide a framework that replaces the MVC parts of ZF with something that allows us to write testable code, whilst still allowing us to use the library parts of ZF, I will - quite literally - buy you a beer.

I'll buy you two beers if you ditch the AJAX. There's a huge gulf between an OO PHP framework and a JavaScript framework.

Answer (score 1):

> Please don't link to an existing framework

I will not, I started writing my own for learning purposes, and took a peek into some of the mainstream frameworks, and even with my limited knowledge see so many mistakes and bad ideas in them.
They're built by hardcore developers, not end users.

I'm in no way saying I could write better than the "big boys" but I (along with most of you I imagine) could point out why some things they do are bad, even if just because they're not end user/non-developer friendly...

I wonder how your framework is doing, some 6 years on?
Are you still working on it? Did you stop?

---

### Should You Write Your Own Framework

This is probably a little late for you, but for anyone else, writing your own framework is a fantastic thing to do for *learning purposes*.

If, however, you are wanting to write one other than learning purposes, because you cannot work out the one you are using, or because it's too bloated, then do not!
Believe me, and don't be insulted, you would not be here contemplating it if you are a knowledgeable enough developer to do so successfully!

Last year I wanted to learn OOP/classes, and more advanced PHP.
And writing my own framework was the best thing I did (am actually still doing), as I have learned so much more than I anticipated.

Along the way I've learned (to name a few):

- [OOP/Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) many best practices which come with it - such as
  Dependency Injection, SRP
- Design patterns, which help you write code and structure your system
  in such a way that it makes many things logical and easy. For an
  example see [Wiki - SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)
- [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)
- [PHP Error Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) and all of the functionality which that provides
- A more robust (and better) understanding of [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]%20mvc), and how to apply it
  appropriately (as there is no clear cut way to use it, just guides
  and best practices).
- [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (of classes for OOP)
- Better code writing style and more structured layout, and better
  commenting skills
- [Naming conventions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196416/whats-the-dominant-naming-convention-for-variables-in-php-camelcase-or-undersc) (it's fun making your own, even if based on
  common practices).

And many other basic PHP things which you invariably come across accidentally from reading something.

All of this not only vastly improved my grasp of PHP and things which come with it, to a more advanced level, but also some of the commercially/widely used methods and principles.
And this all boosted my confidence in using PHP in general, which in turns makes it easier to learn.

---

### Why Write a Framework To Learn All of This

When you start out, you learn the basics - A (variables), then B (how to write a basic function), etc.
But it doesn't take long when you're trying to learn more advanced things,  that to learn and use D and E, you also have to learn and understand F, G, H, and J, and to know those you have to know K, L, and M, and to know parts of L and M you first need to understand N and O...

It becomes a minefield as trying to learn one thing brings the need to first learn a few other things, and those other things often bring a need to understand various other things.
And you end up a mile away from where you started, your mind tingling and shooting sparks from it, and about 20 tabs open all with various advanced PHP things, none of which you are 100% comfortable with.

But over time, with practice and most certainly dedication, it will all fit into place, and you'll look back at code, even a collection of files/classes, and think "Did I write that.."?

**Writing a framework helped greatly with this "minefield" because:**

- I had specific tasks to do, which brought about the need to learn and
  implement other things, but specific things. This allowed me to focus
  on less things at once, and even when something branches off to
  various other things, you can reel it back in to where you started
  because you are working on something specific. You can do this with
  any learning, but if you do not have some goal, or specific task you
  are focusing on, you can easily get distracted and lost in the ether
  of things to learn.
- I had something practical to work with. Often reading tutorials about
  an animal class, and how cat and dog classes extend animal etc,
  can be confusing. When you have a real life task in your *own*
  framework, such as how do I manage XYZ, then you can learn how
  classes work easier because you have trial and error and a solid
  requirement which you understand, because you created the
  requirement! Not just theory-like reading which means nothing
  usually.
- I could put it down when my mind was blown, although as it was my
  framework (my Frankenstein's monster in the beginning :P) I wanted to
  press on, because it was interesting, and a personal goal to learn
  and sort the next stage, to resolve an issue I was stuck with, etc.

You can do it how you want. It might not be best practice, but as long as you are *trying* to learn best practice, over time you will improve, and likely easier than just reading tutorials, because you are in control of what and how you do something.

---

### Wait, I Shouldn't Re-invent the Wheel Though

Well, firstly, you cannot reinvent the wheel, it is impossible, as you will just make a wheel.

When people say "Don't reinvent the wheel", they of course mean "there are already frameworks out there", and to be fair, they are written by skilled developers.
That's not to say the frameworks don't have problems or issues, but in general they are pretty solid, secure and well written.

But the statement is nonsensical in relation to writing your own framework!

Writing your own framework for learning purposes is really useful. 
Even if you plan to use it commercially, or for your own website, you haven't just "re-invented the wheel", you've made something else.
Your framework won't be like the others, it won't have many features and functionality, which might be a major advantage to you!

As long as you understand about best security practices etc, because you can think you are writing a great system, which is super fast and without all the *bloat* other frameworks have, but in fact you have holes in places which someone could crawl into...

But a project for learning which you don't use on the internet is ideal - or use it, eventually, when you are advanced enough to *know* it's secure!

With all that said, you should write your own framework IF:

- You are not needing it any time soon! It takes a lot of time as
  there are so many aspects to consider, learn, and trial and error
  leads to refactoring (a lot at first!)
- You are willing to read, code, test, change, read, code, and read
  some more. There is a lot of good advice on the internet for advanced
  PHP, most of it mind blowing at first, like reading all the design
  patterns. But they eventually make sense, and end up helping you
  resolve problems you face, and how to do things within your
  framework.
- Willing to put the time in, and keep trying to improve, and head
  towards best practice, especially with security. Speed issues shouldn't be an issue with a small framework, and besides, if you have a fairly decent system, you can usually refactor and make speed improvements. usually if you have significant speed issues it means you've chosen intensive operations, which can usually be addressed by doing it a different way.

.

Without previous experience, or an advanced knowledge of PHP, you will likely spend some time writing a framework, further reading and knowledge will show you that your approach is skewed, and so you might delete everything and start again.
Don't be disheartened by this.
I did exactly that, as I learned so much advanced patterns and ways of doing things along the way in the first month, I ended up where refactoring was no good, and a blank canvas with a whole new approach was the only option.

However, this was quite pleasing, as I saw a much better structure take form, and I could see not only a better framework foundation start to take place, but realised it was because I had a better understanding of advanced PHP.

Just do it! Just make sure you have a plan of what you want it to do before you even write some code.
Seriously, write down on paper how you are going to load error checking, are you going to have auto loading, or include files when needed? Are you going to have a centralised loading mechanism, which instantiates classes when you need them, or some other method?

Whatever you do, and whatever stage you are at, if you are heading into new territory, plan it first. You'll be glad of it when you hit a brick wall, can go back to your plans, and realise a slight deviation to your *plans* will resolve it.
Otherwise you just end up with a mess and no plan or way to re-deign it to resolve the current problem or requirement you face.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to build exactly same thing I've worked on for a few years and the result is Agile Toolkit.

### Very easy CRUD page generation

```
$page->add('CRUD')->setModel('User');
```

### AJAX based pagination

All pagination and many other things are implemented through a native support for AJAX and Object Reloading. Below code shows a themed button with random label. Button is reloaded if clicked showing new number.

```
$b=$page->add('Button')->setLabel(rand(1,50));
$b->js('click')->reload();
```

### Ajax based form validation if possible, or very easy form validation

All form validations is AJAX based. Response from server is a JavaScript chain which instructs browser to either highlight and display error message or to redirect to a next page or perform any other javascript action.

### Sortable tables

Table sorting and pagination has a very intuitive and simple implementation when you can really on object reloading.

### Ability to edit HTML templates using PHP

This seems out of place and a wrong thing to do. Templates are better of in the VCS.