# what is a good php mvc framework that is 100% object oriented?

Tags: codeigniter, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fully Object Oriented framework in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535385/fully-object-oriented-framework-in-php)

I am frustrated with CodeIgniter about one thing, you can't extend neither controllers nor models.  I know you can do HMVC with a mod, and that somewhat gives you the inheritance abilities, but I'm not satisfied with that.  Is there a PHP MVC framework that is object oriented and basically allows to extend the controllers, models?

Comment: I haven't used it so I can't say for sure, but I believe Fuel (http://fuelphp.com) was made to improve on that very aspect of CI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) says otherwise - one of first examples is:

> If all you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library - perhaps add a function or two - then it's overkill to replace the entire library with your version. In this case it's better to simply extend the class. Extending a class is nearly identical to replacing a class with a couple exceptions:
>
> The class declaration must extend the parent class.
> Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with `MY_` (this item is configurable. See below.).

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// Then you can use it like this:
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: wow very nice...ok then I can just place the extended class in the same application/controllers folder?

Comment: @user1549397 - you can put them in `application/core` if you are using the 2.x version of CodeIgniter (see the docs I linked to in my answer).

Comment: there anyway to do this w/o altering the codeigniter core?

Comment: @user1549397 You'll be adding a file to the `core` folder not altering any existing files if you follow the method outlined above.

Comment: but in terms of application logic, extending the behavior( in this case the core controller class) is like extending the codeigniter framework right?  Because what i want to be able to do is extend the behavior at the application level.

Comment: @user1549397 - Correct - in your application code you simply extend `My_Controller` rather than `CI_Controller`.

Comment: so i can place the controller that is extending another controller that is in the application/controllers in the same folder?

Comment: @user1549397 `application/core` not `system/...` that's the difference...